# Link error when I use DSIN in fortran

Tags: fortran, linker-errors

My complier is Intel Fortran Compiler 11.0.3451.2005. IDE is Microsoft Visual Studio 2005.
When I use

```
WRITE(*,*) DSIN(0.8)
```

There will be a link error, seems there's no such function. 
Why? How to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dsin` would expect a double precision argument. `sin(0.8d0)` and  `dsin(0.8d0)` are identical.

Just use `sin` and let the machine figure [which version of the sine function](http://www.nsc.liu.se/~boein/f77to90/a5.html) to use, based on the actual type of the argument.

Comment: Exactly. There is (almost) no reason to use DSIN in Fortran 77 and later.